# Can a Document Library URL be changed to a new one

Tags: 2007

Can a document library URL be changed from an existing one to a new one? I am on MOSS and user requested to change the existing document Library URL to a different one. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done fairly simply [in Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904944/change-sharepoint-library-url) or in PowerShell, though I can't seem to find a particularly good example of doing this in PowerShell at the moment.

Yes, you can [use PowerShell to work with SharePoint 2007](http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/01/22/running-powershell-on-moss-2007.aspx), it just doesn't have all the nifty cmdlets that come with SharePoint 2010+.  The full object model is still readily available.

Bear in mind that changing the list URL will break all existing links to that content so some users may complain.

Comment: I tried above steps Open Sharepoint Designer and then open the site which includes the Document Library in question. 2.Click on All files in the Quick Launch menu on the left. 3.In the name column, right-click on the name of the Document Library and select Rename. 4.Change the name by entering it in the name field. 5.Click in another field in the Name column and a dialog will appear briefly indicating that the name is being changed for the Document Library whose name you just changed. 6.The url of the Document Library should have changed by now.Thanks dave

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new document library with the new URL and use Content and Structure or the Explorer Views to move the files from one library to another.

Comment: I could have tried that too but the Doc Lib has many files which will be lot of work so I tried above steps which worked.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to go around this is to save the list as a template with content and then create a new one based on that template.

After this you can delete the original list and the template.

If the list is too large you won't be able to include the content in the template.
In this case create a new empty library using the template and copy the documents using the explorer view which enables copy/paste from two libraries and copy the metadata using the datasheet view.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Slightly late to the part, but you can do the following:

1. Navigate to the Document Library
2. In the Actions select Open using Windows Explorer
3. Navigate up one level
4. Rename the Document Library using a folder rename
5. Navigate to the SITE level and refresh the screen (You can't refresh the DL as you've just changed the URL)
6. And Robert is your mother's brother, changed

Comment: Robert who is what? ;)

Comment: @RobertLindgren, "Robert is your mother's brother" is it.? ;) :P

Comment: Here are the [all three](http://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/change-the-url-of-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/) uncles.